# convert some rows to LBS in R

Tags: r

on of my vectors have diferents kind of data, I’ve been trying to convert it, but I really don find the way.

In te column I have the Weights, the ones with no indicator are in lbs, the others are in KG, I need to have it all in Lbs. But I do not find how to work with an specific number of rows only. To take out Kg, and multiply it by 2.20 to conver it in lbs for example.

- List item

  - Weight
  - 200
  - 150
  - 220
  - 100KG
  - 80KG
  - 95KG

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
# example data
df1 <- read.table(text = "Weight 
1  194 
2  200 
3  250 
4  50Kg 
5  40Kg 
6  39Kg", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# using ifelse (gives warning)
ifelse(grepl("Kg", df1$Weight),
       as.numeric(gsub("Kg", "", df1$Weight)) * 2.2,
       as.numeric(df1$Weight))
# [1] 194.0 200.0 250.0 110.0  88.0  85.8
# Warning message:
# In ifelse(grepl("Kg", df1$Weight), as.numeric(gsub("Kg", "", df1$Weight)) *  :
#    NAs introduced by coercion

# not using ifelse :)
as.numeric(gsub("Kg", "", df1$Weight)) * (1 + grepl("Kg", df1$Weight) * 1.2)
# [1] 194.0 200.0 250.0 110.0  88.0  85.8
```